# Reshift OR query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am currently querying Redshift with a dynamic set of keywords that I return with a series of OR statements using like to fuzzy match e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE key LIKE '%bob%' OR key LIKE '%sid%'
```

This works perfectly however I need to now return an additional column containing the source keyword that it has matched against.  e.g.

```
key    matched
bobby  bob
bobb   bob
sidney sid
side   sid
```

The only solution I can think of is a temp table of keywords and a LEFT JOIN but wondering if there is a better approach?

Comment: What if the key matches both?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking for?

```
   SELECT key, 
    (case when key like '%bob%' then 'bob' else 'sid') as Matched
     FROM 
    blah 
    WHERE 
    key LIKE '%bob%' 
    OR key LIKE '%sid%'
```

these  'bob'  can be input.

if in stored procedure:

`(case when key like '%@input1%' then @input1 else @input2) as Matched`

if directly passing from code (i'll assume c#) (not recommended, but just for understanding):

`"(case when key like '%"+input1+"%' then "+input1+" else "+input2+") as Matched"`

hope it helps. :)

Comment: no stored procedures here - its redshift! the sql looks good but what should happen if the string batches BOTH bob and sid?

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies - for the use case where a target key matches multiple input keys ideally it would output this as a concatenated string - appreciate this will create further complications due to the need to aggregate...

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list in a subquery and do the join instead of OR:

```
WITH 
 filter_values as (
    SELECT 'bob' as val
    UNION SELECT 'sid'
)
SELECT * 
FROM blah 
JOIN filter_values
ON key LIKE '%'||val||'%'
```

Indeed, you mentioned it... and I can't think of another way except a scalar UDF

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This is probably more what you want if you have a second table that has the values to match. This will give multiple results for rows from 'b' that match more than one key selector.

```
SELECT b.*, k.matched
FROM blah b
JOIN keys k on STRPOS(b.key, k.matched) != 0
```

Another probably overly simple and not performative possibility:

```
SELECT *,
    case
        when key LIKE '%bob%' then 'bob'
        when key LIKE '%sid%' then 'sid'
    end as matched
FROM blah
WHERE key LIKE '%bob%' OR key LIKE '%sid%'
```